# How do I add a route query parameter to a ShellContent item in a Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ContentPage that lists purchase requests. I am trying to add a Flyout visual hierarchy to the AppShell.xaml. The navigation needs to have items that will navigate to the same page, but should pass a query parameter which the page will then use to filter the data on the page. So the route attribute needs to looks something like this `Route="purchase-requests?filter=for-me"`.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the app fails with "unable to figure out route for: //fusion/IMPL_purchase-requests?filter=for-me/purchase-requests?filter=for-me/" when I run it.

A more complete sample showing what I need.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Fusion" 
            Route="fusion"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Waiting (for me)"
                  Route="purchase-requests?filter=for-me"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PurchaseRequestsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Waiting (by me)"
                  Route="purchase-requests?filter=by-me"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PurchaseRequestsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Stephen, I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Register the Routes:

```
 void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        routes.Add("monkeydetails", typeof(MonkeyDetailPage));
        routes.Add("beardetails", typeof(BearDetailPage));
        routes.Add("catdetails", typeof(CatDetailPage));
        routes.Add("dogdetails", typeof(DogDetailPage));
        routes.Add("elephantdetails", typeof(ElephantDetailPage));

        foreach (var item in routes)
        {
            Routing.RegisterRoute(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
```

Then navigate to the different page with the Route parameters.

```
            ShellNavigationState state = Shell.Current.CurrentState;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{state.Location}/{destinationRoute}?name={animalName}");
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
```

You could download the source file from the liink below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/

Comment: Thanks for the response Wendy but you misunderstood my problem. Both ShellContent elements point to the same page, but I need to pass different query parameters to the page from each of the routes. This is needed for filtering the data shown on the page.

Comment: The query parameter is not set in the Route property. I would update the reply later. You could download the soure file for reference.

Comment: Thanks Wendy. You keep showing me how to add routes. I know how to add routes. My question is if and how I can specify additional data to be passed to the page when the user taps the FlyoutItem. The FlyoutItem points to a page that contains a CollectionView. It's **not** pointing to a detail page.

Comment: If you want to do the query with route, it could be set in Route of xaml. The URI structure is `// Route + /page? + QueryParameters` => `//route/page?queryParameters`. The sample code you could check it in my reply.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Wendy hasn't addressed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I struggled with this quest and the given answer, here is how I managed to get it done:

1.) Register the route (AppShell.xaml.cs):

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Container), typeof(Container));
```

2.) Define your ShellContent:

```
new ShellContent
{
    Title = "ShellContentTitle",
    Route = $"Container?bookingcodeproperty={queryParam}",
    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Container))
}
```

3.) Add Annotation to view:

```
[QueryProperty("BookingCodeProperty", "bookingcodeproperty")]
```

4.) Set binding context in view:

```
public string BookingCodeProperty
{
    set
    {
        BindingContext = ContainerData.Containers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.BookingCode == Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
    }
 }
```

5.) Have fun.

Comment: This doesn't work actually. When you put parameter to Route property of ShellContent app crashes.

Comment: It didn't crash when I tried it. However, I later encountered other obstacles and ended up using a different approach.
For my programatically created menu and content I'm now using the parameter as Route directly - not as query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simpleworkaround in my solution..
into your landing page you could retrive the route parameter..

This is an example code that working for my shell:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  var arguments = Shell.Current.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.CurrentItem.Route;
}
```

Obviously you need to iterate in your shell's currentItem...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Generate new routes for each parameter:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("page_someId1", typeof(PageView));
Routing.RegisterRoute("page_someId2", typeof(PageView));
```

Step2: Add dynamic ShellContent to Shell

```
shell.Items.Add(new ShellContent
{
    Title = "Page1",
    Route = "page_someId1",
    Icon = "Icon1",
    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PageView))
});

shell.Items.Add(new ShellContent
{
    Title = "Page2",
    Route = "page_someId2",
    Icon = "Icon2",
    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PageView))
});
```

Step3: On your ViewModel handle PageAppearingAsync and parse location

```
private async Task PageAppearingAsync()
{
    string location = Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location.ToString();
    string[] params = location.Split('_');

    if (params.Length == 2)
    {
        string pageId = params[1];
        LoadPage(pageId);
    }
}
```