# Add query parameter to a Xamarin Forms Shell route

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

(Posted this question on the Microsoft forum as well)

Similar to [How do I add a route query parameter to a ShellContent item in a Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433485/how-do-i-add-a-route-query-parameter-to-a-shellcontent-item-in-a-xamarin-forms-a) , but this thread did not help me.

I've recently started a new project and decided to go with Xamarin Forms Shell.

I have a single content page that behaves differently based on the query parameter provided.
There is three tab items that will route to the same content page, each providing a different query parameter.

I can't figure out how to pass this parameter to my content page viewmodel via the AppShell.xaml route.

Please see my sample code below that replicates the requirement.

In ths sample I would like to set the content page label using the query parameter supplied in the xaml route.
Using the code below, I get a null reference exception.

AppShell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Sample">
     <Tab Title="Red">
         <ShellContent Route="SamplePage?Parameter=Red" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Blue">
         <ShellContent Route="SamplePage?Parameter=Blue" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Green">
         <ShellContent Route="SamplePage?Parameter=Green" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
     </Tab>
 </FlyoutItem>
```

SamplePageVM:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Parameter), nameof(Parameter))]
public class SamplePageVM
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

SamplePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
     <Grid>
         <Label Text="{Binding Parameter}"/>
     </Grid>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Or alternative ways to approach this.

Thanks a lot.

*Edit

Below is my workaround for now.

AppShell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Sample">
    <Tab Title="Red">
        <ShellContent Route="RedRoute" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Blue">
        <ShellContent Route="BlueRoute" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Green">
        <ShellContent Route="GreenRoute" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if (args.Target.Location.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains("redroute"))
        {
            StaticHelper.Parameter = "Red";
        }
        else if (args.Target.Location.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains("blueroute"))
        {
            StaticHelper.Parameter = "Blue";
        }
        else if (args.Target.Location.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains("greenroute"))
        {
            StaticHelper.Parameter = "Green";
        }
    }
```

SamplePageVM:

```
public class SamplePageVM
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    public SamplePageVM()
    {
        Parameter = StaticHelper.Parameter;
    }
}
```

SamplePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding Parameter}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Might not be best practice, but it's something.

Comment: This link will help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation?WT.mc_id=shelldata-blog-jamont

Comment: Have you read [Shell navigation- passing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data) ?

Comment: I implemented this workaround for I found it to be a straight forward approach.  I did not build my fly away page structure from scratch, I used the template which builds in the xaml coding and deconstructing and putting all that code behind was a bridge too far.

Answer (score 1):

I could be able to reproduce this exception. Check the screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfuEZ.jpg

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Change the `Route` like below would fix this exception.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Sample">
    <Tab Title="Red">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" Route="Red" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Blue">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" Route="Blue" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Green">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate sample:SamplePage}" Route="Green" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And if you want to use the query parameters, invoke the GoToAsync method with URI which includes all three components, the structure is: `//route/page?queryParameters`.

```
string monkeyName = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Animal).Name;
        // The following route works because route names are unique in this application.
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"routename?Parameter={monkeyName}");
        //routename is the string of the Route in xaml or register the code: Routing.RegisterRoute
```

For more details, you could download the code sample from the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/

Comment: Hi Wendy, thanks for the response. Since I don't have code behind, how/where do I invoke the GoToAsync method ? Do I need to override the default shell navigation?

Comment: No need to override the default shell navigation. You could invoke the GoToAsync method with a triger event like button click or sonething else when you want to do the navigation.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT you do not invoke GoToAsync for Shell flyout item.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set Parameter property directly in Page ViewModel related to route naming without overriding OnNavigating method in Shell:

```
public class SamplePageVM
{
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    public SamplePageVM()
    {
        var route = Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location.OriginalString;
        Parameter = <set parameter related on route ...>;
    }
}
```